# Floated elements leaving gaps (due to different height)

Tags: html, css

I am creating a responsive webpage.

This is what i am trying to do. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ysys540t/1/)

```css
#container {
  max-width:500px;
  width:100%;
  color: #fff;
}
#one {
  width:300px;
  height:200px; 
  background:#66BCD9;
  float:left;
}
#two {
  width:200px;
  height:50px; 
  background:#A1A6E6;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#three {
  width:200px;
  height:50px; 
  background:#E3A1E6;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#four {
  width:300px;
  height:100px; 
  background:#ED5894;
  float:left;
}
#five {
  width:200px;
  height:300px; 
  background:#368736;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#six {
  width:300px;
  height:300px; 
  background:grey;
  overflow:hidden
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="one">#one</div>
  <div id="two">#two</div>
  <div id="three">#three</div>
  <div id="four">#four</div>
  <div id="five">#five</div>
  <div id="six">#six</div>
</div>
```

In desktop view I want #six to touch the bottom of #four.

When you make the screen size small (mobile view) the divs are arranged correctly in order.

How can I make #six touch the bottom of #four in desktop view?

Comment: this has nothing to do with overflow:hidden attribute

Answer (score 0):

The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level container.
    /* Content is clipped, with no scrollbars */
    overflow: hidden;